# PowerShell stop script catch from another script

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, powershell-4.0

I have a problem... I have two ps1 PowerShell scripts:

The first one catches an error like this:

```
$F = "Hola2"
try {
  if ($F -contains "Hola") { write-host "ok" }
  else {
    write-error "Word is not Hola"
    return
  }
}
catch {
  throw
  break
}
```

The other one calls the first one like this:

```
$F1 = "Hola2"

try {
   .\sub1.ps1
   if ($F1 -contains "G") { write-host "ok" }
   else {
     write-error "Word is not Hola2"
     return
   }
}
catch {
  throw
  #Write-Warning "Caught: $_"
}
```

But when I execute the second script the error of the shows up but it doesn't stop, continues and then shows me the second error too. I want to stop at the first script error.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calling the script is what you're doing. It runs in its own context. The outer script will never know about its exception.

Instead, run the second script in the context of the outer by dot sourcing it:

```
. .\sub1.ps1
```

That first dot `.` acts as an include, and its as if that file's code is embedded right at that line.

Comment: @GiuseppeLolli your example doesn't appear to have anything that could throw an exception, so it's hard to tell what the problem could be.